# Why do I have to enter each row when I use pythonista, unlike vscode?

Tags: pythonista

#### Code is:

```
n, m = map(int, input().split())
matrix = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(n)]
```

#### Input is:

```
5 4
0 0 1 0 2
2 3 2 1 0
4 3 2 9 0
1 0 2 9 0
8 8 2 1 0
```

The vscode assigns each line to the variable separately even if multiple lines are entered at the same time. But pythonista occurs  "too many values to unpack (expected 2)" error. Why?? It's so annoying when I try to enter multiple lines.